# Using a batch file, how can I rename this file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename, batch-rename

I'm having issues renaming the following file using a batch (.bat) file. I'm using Windows 7.

Here's my syntax:

```
SET MY_PATH=%~dp0

ren %MY_PATH%\MY_RECAP* DBS.txt
```

I'm attempting to rename a file that has a changing file name due to the current date being appended to the end of the `MY_RECAP` file name (such as `MY_RECAP_MMDDYYYY`). I'm using a wildcard to rename that file to `DBS.txt`

This still won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the path have spaces in it?

Comment: `@For %%A In ("%~dp0MY_RECAP*") Do @If Not Exist "%~dp0DBS.txt" Ren "%%A" "DBS.txt"`

Comment: `ren "%~dp0MY_RECAP*" DBS.txt` or even `move /Y "%~dp0MY_RECAP*" DBS.txt` if `DBS.txt` exists and you want to overwrite it.

Comment: also, are there only one file `my_recap_date` always?

Comment: @Compo that worked. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite many solutions to do this. The first and easier one is:

```bat
@ren "%~dp0MY_RECAP_*" "DBS.txt"
```

If you want to check a `DBS.txt` file already exists, use an `if exist` statement:

```bat
@if not exist "%~dp0DBS.txt" (@ren "%~dp0MY_RECAP_*" "DBS.txt")
```

*An additional note: If in your batch file you have specified somewhere above `@echo off` or `echo off`, remove the `@` symbols from everywhere.*